# Count Orders in multiple Timespans

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Database like this (Standardized, simplified to describe the problem):

```
BOOKS:
ID (PK) | TITLE | AUTHOR | ...
--------|-------|--------|-----
 0 | Title_1 | Author_1 
 1 | Title_2 | Author_1
 2 | Title_3 | Author_2
 3 | Title_3 | Author_3

ORDERs:
ID | BOOK_ID | USER_ID | ORDER_DATE | ...
---|---------|---------|------------|----
 0 | 1 | 1 | 2020-04-10 |
 1 | 2 | 2 | 2020-04-15 |
 2 | 2 | 1 | 2020-04-26 |
 3 | 2 | 1 | 2020-05-02 |
```

What i want to achieve is something like this

```
RESULT:
BOOK | Num_All_Time_Orders | Num_Orders_April | Num_Orders_May
```

As asked for: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e1gW7aVEh3Gh547nZHvaDA/0

Basically Count all Orders for each Book. The All Time part was quite easy but I am trying to get a View for 'all' timespans.

Is this possible (in an easy manner) or should I do subsequent queries with different parameters?

The current query for NumAllTime looks something like this:

```
SELECT BOOK.ID , COUNT(ORDERS.BOOK_ID)
FROM BOOKS AS BOOK
LEFT JOIN ORDERS ON BOOK.ID = ORDERS.BOOK_ID
GROUP BY BOOK.ID
```

EDIT: Thanks for the immediate Comments. Edited some Stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine current month and last month orders by counting only values which have the same month as either now or one month earlier:

```
SELECT b.ID,
       COUNT(o.ID) AS All_Orders,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM o.ORDER_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE()) THEN 1 END) AS This_Month_Orders,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM o.ORDER_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN 1 END) AS Last_Month_Orders
FROM BOOKS b
JOIN ORDERS o ON o.BOOK_ID = b.ID
GROUP BY b.ID
```

Output:

```
ID  All_Orders  This_Month_Orders   Last_Month_Orders
1   1           0                   1
2   3           1                   2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c42ex3d5dMazs6CySrFCbN/0)

Comment: Awesome how quick you put together the dbfiddle code. This seems to work just i wanted.

Comment: @recklessGreed thank the "text to ddl" button! :-) I'm glad this helped.

Comment: must have missed that. Well thank you again, will use this anytime soon. This wont be my last question i am sure.